# Convert EPOCH date to timestamp in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I get a date format EPOCH in database table - "19072"

First I need to convert to time- 21/03/2022 and concatenate 23:59:59
date conversion reference - https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=1&m1=1&y1=1970&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=19072&rec=

Now I need to convert "21/03/2022 23:59:59" to UTC +7:00(Jakarta, Indonesia)
Final expected output is - "22/03/2022 06:59:59"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a number of days directly to a date:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + 19072 from dual;
```

```
21-MAR-22
```

or add an interval to a timestamp; which is probably more appropriate as you need to end up with a timestamp with time zone anyway, so this starts with a UTC value:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + (19072 * interval '1' day) from dual;
```

```
21-MAR-22 00.00.00.000000000 PM UTC
```

Then you can add hours, minutes and seconds (or go ahead another day and subtract one second):

```
select 
  timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
    + (19072 * interval '1' day)
    + (23 * interval '1' hour)
    + (59 * interval '1' minute)
    + (59 * interval '1' second)
from dual;
```

```
21-MAR-22 11.59.59.000000000 PM UTC
```

and convert to your target time zone with `at time zone`:

```
select
  (
    timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
      + (19072 * interval '1' day)
      + (23 * interval '1' hour)
      + (59 * interval '1' minute)
      + (59 * interval '1' second)
  )
  at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta'
from dual;
```

```
22-MAR-22 06.59.59.000000000 AM ASIA/JAKARTA
```

and then for display purposes, convert to a string in the format you want:

```
select
  to_char(
    (
      timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        + (19072 * interval '1' day)
        + (23 * interval '1' hour)
        + (59 * interval '1' minute)
        + (59 * interval '1' second)
    )
    at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta',
    'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  ) as result
from dual;
```

```
22/03/2022 06:59:59
```

You can simplify a bit by modifying your epoch, though it looks a bit odd:

```
select
  to_char(
    (
      timestamp '1970-01-01 23:59:59 UTC'
        + (19072 * interval '1' day)
    )
    at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta',
    'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  ) as result
from dual;
```

```
22/03/2022 06:59:59
```

(I'd probably prefer to keep the usual epoch and do the extra explicit interval additions...)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2767f5923b22936d5b4b2febe13ea9f1)

Only format as a string to display it. If you need to pass the value somewhere else then leave it as a timestamp with time zone, or if necessary cast that to a plain timestamp or even a date.